# Modify data structure of a view REST export

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I need to build a sitemap.xml with a REST export with a view.
By default I get this data structure with a REST export.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <response>
    <item key="0">
      <field1>...
```

How can I modify the tags of this structure? I need to get this tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
      <loc>...
```

These tags must be changed.

```
<response> > <urlset...
<item> > <url>
```

Do I write a custom serializer for the REST export or a specific encoder? How do I proceed?

Answer (score -1):

In D8 you need to create custom serializer and encoder to alter the XML tags.

1. Create custom serializer
   Ref :  https://gist.github.com/BERRAMOU/dd21e009eec0e3d98733e78360122892
2. Write custom encoder

-

```
namespace Drupal\custom_serializer;
use Drupal\serialization\Encoder\XmlEncoder as SerializationXMLEncoder;
use SimpleXMLElement;
 /**
 * Encodes xml API data.
 *
 * @internal
 */
class myXMLEncoder extends SerializationXMLEncoder {

  /**
   * The formats that this Encoder supports.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected static $format = ['myxml'];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getBaseEncoder() {
    $base_encoder = parent::getBaseEncoder();
    $base_encoder->setRootNodeName('jobs');
    return $base_encoder;
  }
}
```

3. Then in View under 'FORMAT' you will see both options.
4. After save, you should get XML with required tag.